# custom text constrains in JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

How do I add custom text constrains to JTextField?

For example, I would like users to provide input in such format:
12-100 
78-023

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using a [JFormattedTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)? Sounds like just what you need.

Comment: examples here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Formatted-TextField.htm +1